# SoapClient PHP returns error

Tags: php, soap

I am tying to get a simple SOAP call to work in php, but I have no clue what is wrong.
It is my first time using soap so please be gentle :)

when I make a manual call like this, it all workes

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header>
  <tem:AuthenticationHeader>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:UserName>****</tem:UserName>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:Password>***</tem:Password>
  </tem:AuthenticationHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
 <tem:SignUp>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:email>test@test.se</tem:email>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:password>password</tem:password>
  </tem:SignUp>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when i do it in php, i get " Function ("SignUp") is not a valid method for this service"

```
try {
    $soap_client = new SoapClient("http://url.com/Service.asmx?WSDL");
    $soapHeader = array('UserName' => '*****','Password' => '***');
    // Soap Header initialization
    $header = new SOAPHeader('http://tempuri.org/', 'AuthenticationHeader', $soapHeader);        
    // add the Header to the Soap Client before request
    $soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header); 
    $args  = array('email'=>'tetsing@pp.se','password' =>'tetsing');
    $user = $soap_client->SignUp($args);
    print_r($user);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

edit1: Added WSDL

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <s:element name="AuthenticationHeader" type="tns:AuthenticationHeader"/>
    <s:complexType name="AuthenticationHeader">...</s:complexType>
    <s:element name="SignUp">
      <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="email" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
     </s:element>
```

Edit 2:

Edit 3: getFunctions gives med

```
    array(18) {
  [0]=>
  string(80) "GetGameProgressDataResponse GetGameProgressData(GetGameProgressData $parameters)"
  [1]=>
  string(101) "GetGameParticipantPicturesResponse GetGameParticipantPictures(GetGameParticipantPictures $parameters)"
  [2]=>
  string(41) "SignUpResponse SignUp(SignUp $parameters)"
  [3]=>
  string(38) "LoginResponse Login(Login $parameters)"
  [4]=>
  string(53) "CreateGameResponse CreateGame(CreateGame $parameters)"
  [5]=>
  string(62) "GetActivitiesResponse GetActivities(GetActivities $parameters)"
  [6]=>
  string(62) "SetActivitiesResponse SetActivities(SetActivities $parameters)"
  [7]=>
  string(68) "GetParticipantsResponse GetParticipants(GetParticipants $parameters)"
  [8]=>
  string(68) "SetParticipantsResponse SetParticipants(SetParticipants $parameters)"
  [9]=>
  string(80) "GetGameProgressDataResponse GetGameProgressData(GetGameProgressData $parameters)"
  [10]=>
  string(101) "GetGameParticipantPicturesResponse GetGameParticipantPictures(GetGameParticipantPictures $parameters)"
  [11]=>
  string(41) "SignUpResponse SignUp(SignUp $parameters)"
  [12]=>
  string(38) "LoginResponse Login(Login $parameters)"
  [13]=>
  string(53) "CreateGameResponse CreateGame(CreateGame $parameters)"
  [14]=>
  string(62) "GetActivitiesResponse GetActivities(GetActivities $parameters)"
  [15]=>
  string(62) "SetActivitiesResponse SetActivities(SetActivities $parameters)"
  [16]=>
  string(68) "GetParticipantsResponse GetParticipants(GetParticipants $parameters)"
  [17]=>
  string(68) "SetParticipantsResponse SetParticipants(SetParticipants $parameters)"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of the WSDL?  This probably has something to do with `$soap_client` not knowing the namespace for `SignUp`.

Comment: It is now in the post, thanks!

Comment: Is that all of it?  Usually the types are used in message definitions, and those messages are used in operation definitions.  SoapClient is probably looking at the rest to decide what are the allowed method calls.

Comment: Sorry for this late answer, that is not all of it, but it's seams that i dont know what is importent and not :) I added a link to the full url. /Thanks

Comment: OK, what does `getFunctions` give you?  http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getfunctions.php

Comment: I have now added the output

Comment: Edit:
It seams like the server backed was to blame, yesterday. __getFunctions did not list all functions present in the WSDL, but now they did, and the code works fine.

How can I thank you? Can i add to your rep without you posting an "answer post"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was fine, it was a server problem, and they fixed.